# How can i create a seamless blend between two objects and give the illusion of rubber stretching?

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials

I'm trying to recreate this seamless, stretchy illusion between the character and environment as seen here: [image]

[image]

but have no idea how to do it? I've tried extruding particular faces of the floor plain but when it comes to curving it, the "stretchy cord" just doesn't look right, can anyone help me?

(images by Jun Seo Hahm)

Comment: Have you tried just adding a subdivision modifier to your extrusions so it does the smoothing for you?

Comment: What do you mean by when it comes to curving the stretchy cord doesn't look right? Please show some screenshots of your wireframe. Are you supposed to animate? If not you can just create a grid, subsurf it, then select a square, make it circular with shift alt S, and extrude up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't tell enough about the difficulty you meet, but I guess the way to do it is the following one:

- Create a plane, subdivide it, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.
- Cut a hole, select the borders and make it a circle with <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and drag.
- Extrude up with <kbd>E</kbd>, scale down the new circle.
- Go on...

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! i'm pretty much an amateur at blender so i don't even know any of the terminology to use to describe the problem, but this definitely helps.

Answer (score 5):

Add a plane with some subdivisions: hit W then S (in 2.79) a few times. Add a cube above it, adjust its scale then subdivide it a few times. Delete the faces at the legs in the cube and in the plane (one face/leg). Select the edges around the holes both on the cube and the floor, then bridge them with "Bridge edge loops" command. Then add a "Subdivision surface" modifier to the mesh. You can correct the legs with new edge loops by hitting ctrl+p.
[image]